# Apache camel simple http example

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I am pretty new with Camel. I have been trying to fetch a data from http source.
Here's my code:

```
from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1")
    .to("http4://webservice.com/example.xml")
    .process(new structureXML())
    .to("mock:resource")
    .stop();
```

And:

```
class structureXML implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange httpExchange) throws Exception {
        String httpres = httpExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String[] lines = httpres.split("\n");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<Map Key='(.+)' Value='(.+)'/>");
        HashMap<String, Integer> mapdata = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for(String line : lines) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

            if(m.find())
                mapdata.put(m.group(1), Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)));
        }

        httpExchange.getIn().setBody(mapdata);
    }
}
```

Well the example works right but I want to know about the possible ways to further improve this situation(e.g xml processing using xpath and etc), also I want to know about the ways which I can store the java object inside the message so I can use it in another route(e.g: direct:resource instead of mock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*About java objects:*

More information can be found here: http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html

- JAXB
- XStream
- BeanIO
- JiBX
- XmlBeans

These data formats will be very useful for transforming XML to POJO.
I recomend you to try **BeanIO** (detailed documentation, many examples, etc).

*About Xpath:*

it's hard to tell anything specified without web-service response.

Example:

```
setBody().xpath("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/s:insertResponse/s:data",
            XmlNamespaces.getNamespace()).
```

*About your example:*

You usually need to set a lot of properties and header (before http request), so it worked fine. Example:

```
    setProperty(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE).constant("application/soap+xml").
    setProperty(Exchange.CONTENT_ENCODING).constant("gzip").
    setProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME).constant("utf-8").
    setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE).exchangeProperty(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE).
```

And I don't see creating the request to web-service. It is easy to do with the help of **velocity** (http://camel.apache.org/velocity.html), or, maybe, using SOAP date format (http://camel.apache.org/soap.html).

You can use **jetty** (http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) instead of **http4** (for me it's easier)